# shift-js generates error when trying to npm install

Tags: node.js, git, npm

I can't seem to npm install this repository in github: https://github.com/shift-js/shift-js.git

everytime i do `npm install`, it generates the following error: 
npm ERR! code 1 
npm ERR! Command failed: git checkout master 
npm ERR! error: pathspec 'master' did not match any file(s) known to git

Any tips on how to install it properly?
(current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

Comment: can u please share ur package.json

Comment: check this solution maybe it works for you https://stackoverflow.com/a/53005292/10079978